# boot luakit (or midori) on bare X11 desktop (kiosk app, PI3, jessie)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, touchscreen, xorg, midori

I'm developing a kiosk app using PI3 and the PI Touchscreen. The app is served on localhost. I'm looking for the bare minimum wm that will allow the browser (either luakit or midori) to run and respond to touch events.

The accepted answer to a related question  ([Possible to reinstall X server and use graphical after having removed it?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26836/possible-to-reinstall-x-server-and-use-graphical-after-having-removed-it))
notes that X without a DM or WM will provide a bare minimum black screen and mouse pointer.

That sounds like exactly what I want. I don't want the users to be able to get to a login or anything other than what's showing in the browser.  Which config files do I need to alter to disable the default desktop and window manager?

Thanks!

Comment: This might save you some time https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thanks, that looks worth considering. I need to read it more deeply to figure out how it differs, beyond the desktop, from the standard Raspbian.