# How to automatically boot into desktop mode

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-wheezy

I accidentally selected the option of booting to terminal during the initial configuration, now I have to type startx to get the desktop environment, how can I get it to boot to desktop GUI automatically?

Comment: @IRO-bot Although I see your point, the question and correct answer are the reverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up a terminal and type:

```
 $ sudo raspi-config
```

This is a duplicate question, see full answer here: [Boot without starting X-server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/boot-without-starting-x-server)

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. How is disabling the x-server going to help boot to desktop? Isn't x-server needed for it?