# Trying to turn off X11 in Jessie

Tags: boot, xorg, raspbian-jessie

I am running Debian Jessie which uses SystemD. I have so far been unable to find a way to stop X11 from starting on bootup. The raspi-config setting apparently does not do anything.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using systemd w/ jessie?

Comment: @goldilocks : systemd came free with jessie. I didn't specifically request it.

Comment: All apologies -- I did not notice you mentioned systemd in the original question.

Comment: I just created a new SD card from the latest image ("2015-11-21" at the time) from the Raspberry Pi site. Modifying the `3 Boot Options` setting in raspi-config to `B1 Console` worked fine for me on next reboot. They may have fixed an issue.

Answer (score 18):

Systemd users "service bunlde" named target, to achieve different system states while booting the system. You need to change the desired state of the system, from graphical to multi-user.

Run

```
systemctl get-default
```

Will show you

> graphical.target

You could change it with

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

I could recommend this article to understand how to work with systemd
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Comment: Thank you, `raspi-config` wasn't working for me. This is exactly what I needed on Stretch.

Answer (score 2):

The GUI login is `lightdm` (the `dm` is for [display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type))).  This is started as an init service, and the init system on Jessie is systemd.

I believe the name of the service is also "lightdm".  You can confirm that:

```
systemctl list-units | grep lightdm
```

The middle columns should say "loaded active" and the first one "lightdm.service".  Presuming that's it, to disable on boot:

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm
```

Comment: I have tried it, and lightdm still comes up on reboot.

Comment: Go figure.  Try `update-rc.d lightdm disable` as well; I haven't had much of a look at whatever transitional mess is involved in Debian switching to systemd.    If all that doesn't work just uninstall the whole thing (`apt-get remove lightdm`), and if that doesn't work give up -- your system is haunted ;)

Comment: I even tried systemctl mask, and it still brings back lighted. Also I tried "systemctl disable graphical", and it also fails. I believe my machine is haunted.

Comment: If you've tried both `update-rc.d disable` and `systemctl disable`, at this point it shouldn't be considered anything other than a screw-up by the Raspbian crew and you should report it as such (https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs).    I have an upgraded-to-jessie pi, but lightdm was removed before the upgrade; there is no reason a GUI login should be inescapable on any GNU/Linux system.   The easy way for you, if you don't care, should be just the `apt-get remove`; doing a bug report is more tedious, but if you are up to it, **remember to give them a link to here in the report.**

Answer (score 2):

This worked on my Raspbian/Jessie:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

I can still manually start lightdm via

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

or

```
sudo lightdm
```

Answer (score 0):

The Debian way to enable or disable services is to use update-rc.d. You can use

```
update-rc.d lightdm disable
```

if in fact lightdm is the display manager installed.

If you need to run it once, you can

```
service lightdm start
```

**update** the systemd way to do it is in fact to use systemctl disable like indicated in the other answer

Comment: "The Debian way" here is their twist/tweak on [the SysV init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SYSV) way of doing things.   Debian used SysV for ~20 years, *up until Jessie*, and the default is now **systemd.**  
They have ([apparently](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd/Integration)) added functionality to `update-rc.d` to make it work with systemd for people used to doing it the old way, but if this is all new to you, you might as well learn the new way -- SysV is now pretty much dead on linux.

Comment: As you say it, update-rc still works with systemd so why not use it? Debian, as other distributions, has a lot of scripts to manage the system, I don't see a reason to not use them. But I'm willing to learn the systemd way of doing it if you know it.

Comment: hum maybe the 'systemctl disable lightdm' you indicated in the answer is this way. I read it quickly and thought it was a command to disable it once and not forever.

Comment: It's the same as sysv that way, there's *stop* and *disable*.  WRT how you do it, if there's a way you are familiar and comfortable with that works then there's no harm in sticking with it (at least for a while), but if you are new to all this init service stuff (I'm presuming the OP is), then it would be a bit silly to start learning depreciated methodologies.