# Emulationstation on new RPI OS

Tags: pi-3, emulation

I have formatted my RPI3 SD card to run the new Raspbian OS (with new skin and such). The problem is that I used to run Emulationstation on that SD card; so I did try to install it manually, instead than running the Retropie image directly.

The problem is that at boot, the X server start, even if I set it to not start (in the raspi-config util); and then it quit to terminal, but when I run emulationstation command, I get an error that say that X is running and I need to shut it down.

So I did log in at boot, and launched the desktop environment; then I did logout via the menu, and still I get the same error saying that X is running.

How do I get the RPI to start in console directly, without start the desktop process, so I can run Emulationstation directly at boot? And why "startx" does not work anymore, once that I am in console? The only way to get to the desktop seems to be to reboot the PI.

Comment: Asked and answered here:  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/boot-without-starting-x-server

Comment: Sadly it is neither the right question nor the right answer. I am aware of how to set the boot flags to get directly in X server, the issue is that it won't take the command to start X. Also the main question is how do I turn off X, once that I do log out from it; because it doesn't seem to shut down unless I kill the process by hand